# .toggleClass not working with .live

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a .toggleClass working on a form that I have multiple text/inputs in but its not working the way I'd like. I want all the input[type="text"] fields on the page to have this functionality. Some fields are static and some are added with .append and .live those are not working right. Basically I want a function that works for all fields static or dynamic.

### Code not working

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $(this).live('focusin, blur', function() {
        $(':input[type="text"]').bind('focusin blur', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('fieldFocus');  
        })
    });
});
```

### Works for static ones

```
$(':input[type="text"]').bind('focusin blur', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('fieldFocus');
    });
```

I'm sure it's a basic problem, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

### Works!

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        $(':input[type="text"]').live('focusin blur', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('fieldFocus');  
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(':input[type="text"]').live('focusin blur', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('fieldFocus');
});
```

**Edit:**
Just for note - jQuery 1.7 introduced new interface for events, to the above example would look like this:

```
$(document).on('focusin focusout', ':text', function(){
    $(this).toogleClass('fieldFocus');
});
```

It also uses shortcut `:text` as pointed out by **scumah**, and `focusout` as pointed out by **Bryan Ross**, and due to fact, that `blur` does not bubble in IE (jQuery uses `focusout` to get round this).

Note, that instead of `document` you should use another element - the best would be container you are filling with AJAX.

Answer (score 3):

From the [`live()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> the string can contain multiple, space-separated event types or custom event names

You're using a comma at the moment :)

(`.live('focusin, blur'` should be `.live('focusin blur'`)

Answer (score 2):

This code should work, check this fiddle out: http://jsfiddle.net/W83Du/

```
$(':text').live('focusin blur', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('fieldFocus');  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the `focusin` event is paired with `focusout`, and `focus` is paired with `blur`. Also, when calling live, separate the events you want to attach with spaces, not commas, like so:

```
$(this).live('focusin focusout')
```

instead of

```
$(this).live('focusin, focusout')
```